# Inverse of $f(x) = 3x + \cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse

Was hoping someone could help me find the inverse of $f(x) = 3x + \cos(x)$

The steps I took were:

$y = 3x + \cos(x)$

$x = 3y + \cos(y)$

$x - 3y = \cos(y)$

$\arccos(x-3y) = y $

But I still have a $y$ in the $\arccos$ , and I don't know how to isolate it.

Comment: It is not possible to give a closed expression for this function.

Comment: The inverse is a real analytic function, you can sole for a power series around any point of interest; in any case, an asymptotic series is easy enough

Comment: is your task to find the inverse, or to prove it exists?

Answer (score 2):

$$y=3x+\cos x$$
$$y-3x=\cos x$$
$$x=\cos^{-1}(y-3x)$$
when $|y-3x|<1$
$$x=\cos^{-1}(y-3\cos^{-1}(y-3\cos^{-1}(y-3\cos^{-1}(y-3\cos^{-1}(y-3\cos^{-1}(y-3(....)))))$$